# Why is connecting to SQL Server very slow?

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection

We see that creating new connections takes about 250 milliseconds, which is much slower than expected.

From our application server to the SQL Server, we have about 1 millisecond ping-time, and we are operating inside pretty fast LAN.

Our connection string is:

```
Data Source=SQLServer;Initial Catalog=Database;Integrated Security=True
```

I have measured elapsed time around this simple statement

```
var conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);

if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    await conn.OpenAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    sw.StopAndLogIfDelay(20, _log, "Open SQL Server connection");
}
```

I would not expect 250 milliseconds to connect in a fast LAN. Does anyone have ideas or experience in where the problem could be?

Comment: Connections are fairly expensive resources which is why they're usually pooled. How long does it take when you dispose of that connection then get another one?

Comment: You are going through a driver and windows timers.   It is not just a TCP connections.  what is the time for synchronous instead of asynchronous?

Comment: You can consider Connection Pooling implementation.

Comment: Note that you are using Windows authentication so a DC is involved in the authentication process. I'd expect subsequent connections to be much faster due to default connection pooling mentioned in the other comments.

Comment: @jdweng sync connect time is about the same as async (with await)

Comment: I hear consensus about connection pooling. Maybe sql-connections really are so expensive that I should just add more to the pool. The problem is that our web-server would suddenly get 1 or 2000 requests. SQL-client would then start adding to the pool and that took time. So I guess setting a higher minimum could solve it. I am just disappointed that it is necessary.

Comment: try using IP instead of Server Name

Comment: @TorbenNielsen, yes, a min pool size will help reduce latency during a flood of activity but should be use judiciously since each uses both client and server resources. I've seen cases where connection slowness was due to slow name resolution, inadvertent routing of authentication requests to a remote data center DC, or slowness in DC responses. 250ms is quite high but much depends on your infrastructure.

Comment: @FLICKER Thanks. I have tried using ip instead of dns-name to avoid dns-lookup. Made no difference. Appearantly it is not the dns-lookup in my case

Comment: @DanGuzman Thanks. I added a min pool size of 50 last night. Have not seen the problem since. I would like to see a full working days load, before I declare the problem solved though.

Comment: @TorbenNielsen, 50 isn't unreasonable so I'm glad it stopped the bleeding. I suspect root cause is authentication slowness since you've ruled out name resolution. The DC routing issue I mentioned earlier was identified by our network team with a network trace of the database and application traffic, which showed authentication traffic to a remote DR data center, over a thousand miles away. Light only travels so fast.

Comment: @DanGuzman I have no idea how integrated security works in sql-server. Is the DC contated from the SQL-server or from the SQL-client? Or both?

Comment: Both client and server, hence the need to trace both client and server. I only have a cursory understanding of the details but it's a lot more complex than you might think at first glance. See [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/windows-authentication/credentials-processes-in-windows-authentication). I'd expect only a couple of milliseconds when all is healthy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting minimum connections to 50 in th sql-server connection pool solved the immidate problem.

What remains is to investigate why open db-connections takes such a long time in our organisation. I will ally with our network-team to see if we can locate the problem.